# Replacing element text in BeautifulSoup list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I currently trying to achieve something here - but sort of ran into a roadblock. Hoping you kind folks can help me out here.

Given there is two `classes` - `a` and `b`. I would like to replace the element text **scraped** from the site with a `True` or `False` text.

Below is my code snippet:

```
fp_page = requests.get("https://www.kidocode.com/kmath")
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp_page.content, 'html.parser')

oss = ["a","b"]
raw_is_avail = soup.find_all('div', class_=oss)
for i in range(len(raw_is_avail)):
 if raw_is_avail[i].class_ == "a":
     'True'
 else:
     'False'
 cleansed_avail.append(raw_is_avail[i])

print(cleansed_avail)
```

Current Output:
`['foo','bar','foo','bar']`

Expected Output:
`['True','False','True','False']`

Please advise. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: understood, thanks for pointing out. i've rephrased it - please do have a look. appreciate it!

Comment: After your update, please show where your current output is coming from.

Comment: noted with thanks. i've elaborated on the code.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension to generate `cleansed_avail`:

```
cleansed_avail = [item.class_ == "a" for item in raw_is_avail]
```

This will create a list of `True`/`False` (boolean, not string) values based on the items in `raw_is_avail`, i.e. `True` if `item.class_ == "a"`, `False` otherwise.
Output:

```
[True, False, True, False]
```

If needed as string values, you can cast the booleans to strings:

```
cleansed_avail = [str(item.class_ == "a") for item in raw_is_avail]
```

Output:

```
['True', 'False', 'True', 'False']
```

If you're not familiar with these list comprehensions, the "loopy" form of this would be:

```
cleansed_avail = []
for item in raw_is_avail:
    cleansed_avail.append(str(item.class_ == "a"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the strings 'True' and 'False'. I am guessing you wanted them appended to `cleansed_avail`.

```py
oss = ["a","b"]
raw_is_avail = soup.find_all('div', class_=oss)
for i in range(len(raw_is_avail)):
    if raw_is_avail[i].class_ == "a":
        cleansed_avail.append('True')
    else:
        cleansed_avail.append('False')
```